# Flutter Listview.builder - Build a list with a specific children into ROW

Tags: flutter

What I want to do is to build with flutter a list with specific Rows with children Like this code I have done:

```
                  Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: ListView(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
                            Text('#9u48r92'),
                            Text('Amazon'),
                            Text('359€'),
                            Text('Spedito'),
                            Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
                            Text('#9u48r92'),
                            Text('Amazon'),
                            Text('359€'),
                            Text('Spedito'),
                            Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
                            Text('#9u48r92'),
                            Text('Amazon'),
                            Text('359€'),
                            Text('Spedito'),
                            Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
                            Text('#9u48r92'),
                            Text('Amazon'),
                            Text('359€'),
                            Text('Spedito'),
                            Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
                            Text('#9u48r92'),
                            Text('Amazon'),
                            Text('359€'),
                            Text('Spedito'),
                            Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
                            Text('#9u48r92'),
                            Text('Amazon'),
                            Text('359€'),
                            Text('Spedito'),
                            Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
                            Text('#9u48r92'),
                            Text('Amazon'),
                            Text('359€'),
                            Text('Spedito'),
                            Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
                            Text('#9u48r92'),
                            Text('Amazon'),
                            Text('359€'),
                            Text('Spedito'),
                            Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 5,)
                    ],
                  ),
```

This code allow me to have this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/py8Aj.png)

What I want is to get the List I have done repeating the code, get it automaticaly specifing the number of list to be created with these items into the row
Second question:
to get this list from API I can use future builder widget or I can alwais use listview.builder?
Thanks

Comment: Use Future.Builder, it should give you a list from server,  and render that list using Listview.Builder

Comment: Do you have any example how to retrieve data from server and display to flutter widget?